# Why ngIf has higher priority than {{ }} (interpolate)?

Tags: angularjs

What is the reasoning behind setting `ngIf` priority (600) higher than `{{ }}`(100)? Shouldn't it have a lower priority to allow `{{ }}` inside `ng-if` attribute value?

I would like to have a condition inside a `$scope` variable:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $parse) {
  $scope.hide = "check === 'hidden'";
  $scope.parsecond = function (cond) {
    return $parse(cond)($scope);
  };

});
```

Template:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-if="!{{hide}}">funky ng-if div</div>
    <div ng-hide="{{hide}}">ng-hide div</div>
    <div ng-if="!parsecond(hide)">ng-if div</div>
    <input type="input" ng-model="check" />
  </body>
```

`ng-hide` works fine since it parses the contents of the hide variable and returns "check === 'hidden'" which then gets evaluated by `ng-hide` directive.

But `ng-if` tries to evaluate `{{hide}}` before interpolate has had a chance to parse the string hence  `ng-if` throws an exception.

The only solution I've found is call a function that basically does the job of the interpolate directive and returns the parsed content.

Plnkr showing the issue: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/nAJmFt9nP8CNS0osqsHS?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

After reading documentation I've found better way of doing it without the need of a custom method on the `$scope` since angularjs has already a method that parses a variable against its current `$scope` (`$eval`).

So my solution would be:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-if="!$eval(hide)">funky ng-if div</div>
    <div ng-hide="{{hide}}">ng-hide div</div>
    <div ng-if="!parsecond(hide)">ng-if div</div>
    <input type="input" ng-model="check" />
  </body>
```

Updated plnkr: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/JxTbkkv9Gqg7PZJLKWcX?p=preview)

Although this still doesn't explain why ngIf has higher priority.

**EDIT 2:**

Just so people understand that it's not the same:

For example:

Controller:

```
$scope.value = "hi";
$scope.condition = "value === 'bye'";
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-hide="condition"></div> <!--This will be evaluated to true since !!"value ==='bye'" = true. -->
<div ng-hide="{{condition}}"></div> <!--This will be evaluated to false since value !== 'bye' = false -->
<div ng-if="condition"></div> <!--This will be evaluated to true since !!"value === 'bye'" = true. -->
<div ng-if="{{condition}}"></div> <!--This will give an exception since ngIf directive ran before interpolation directive in the $compile step. -->
<div ng-if="$eval(condition)"></div> <!--This will be evaluated to false since value !== 'bye' = false. -->
```

My conclusion is that it safer to use `$parse` if you want the directive to evaluate/set a watch in the string rather than in the property on the scope. Although it's true that I could use `{{ }}` for `ng-hide`/`ng-show` or any directive that has a lower priority than 100 but I'm guessing it's not safe since I'm depending in the compiling order and it's not 100% clear that it won't change in future patches.

Comment: Please explain the down-vote so I can improve my question.

Comment: Thanks man! I did copy ng-if source code to create a directive for checking permissions as well and was exactly stuck at that point. The interpolate wasn't getting evaluated. So I removed the priority which made it 0.
Now, it was not working with adjacent directives. Now as soon as I brought back the priority to 99. 
Everything was fine and awesome!

Comment: A poor choice in my opinion. I was getting errors in the console due to  transclude: "element" on an element which used interpolation. The interpolation service was attempting to set attributes on the comment element, by-product of the element transclusion.

Answer (score 5):

`ng-if` expects its value to **be an angular expression** - [under the hood](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L3) it just makes use of `$scope.$watch`. Therefore, if you want to condition including content of `ng-if` on some variable defined on the scope (let say: `scope.hide`), you put `ng-if="hide"` in your mark-up. No double curly braces here.

Now back to your question: it is true that `ng-if` has priority of `600`, but [`$interpolate`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/interpolate.js#L86) is angular's service - not a directive. As such `$interpolate` does not define priority. Where did you get `100` from?

#### UPDATE

You can always condition including content of `ng-if` on some function (let say `scope.conditionFn`) by putting in your mark-up: `ng-if="conditionFn()"`.

#### UPDATE 2

I updated your [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/PFiZ2O8ICvSvS1tySUXe?p=preview) to make it working. <del>The inconsistencies between `ng-if` and `ng-hide` in your plunker had nothing to do with priority of interpolation taking place in `$compile`.</del>

#### UPDATE 3

It seems that you are right that order of interpolation plays a role here, but... I really **do not see** any good reason to interpolate inside of angular's expression. The reason why `ng-if` has relatively high priority is that it removes/adds transcluded content from/to DOM, whereas `ng-hide` just shows/hides the transcluded content. I think it is a pure coincidence that one directive *seems* to work and the other not. **But** if you do not use unnecessary, superfluous tricks, both **do work** as intended, what my plunker shows.

Comment: if you put ng-if="hide" it's just going to evaluate !!$parse(hide) which will be equal to !!("check === 'hidden'") which is true and thats not what I want.

@interpolate priority here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/79223eae5022838893342c42dacad5eca83fabe8

Comment: I'm the down-voter, read my comment. What you are saying is simply not true and it's not answering my question. "double curly braces" (interpolate) gets treated as a directive by angularjs and it does have a priority of 100. My question is why ngif doesn't have lower priority so interpolate has time to run as with ng-hide (both ng-if and ng-hide expect an angularjs expression but ng-hide has default priority (0) and ng-if has 600). And just so you know ng-hide="hide" and ng-hide="{{hide}} it's not the same they mean completely different things.

Comment: @Wawy about `$interpolate` - the link you provided is about `$compile` not `$interpolate`.

Comment: @Wawy I updated your plunker to show you that you are not right - just type `hidden` into the input.

Comment: I don't see how that proves anything. The point still remains `ng-hide="{{hide}}"` works and `ng-if="{{hide}}"` doesn't and that is because of the $compile priorities.

Comment: Your plnkr doesn't show anything new, I know that I can define a function in the $scope that does the job of `{{ }}`. And if you read my edit of my question you'd realise that you don't even need to use a custom function since you can use built in $eval which does exactly the same as the custom function in the scope. I don't know what do you mean by superfluous tricks but it's a legit thing to try to contain a condition inside a variable.

Answer (score 0):

To understand why it's doing that, observe the console of [this sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/MoonStorm/qbge5qse/), where the custom directive, similar to `ngIf`, sits this time at priority 0. The directive is meant to remove the element and, without waiting, to add it back. You'll see however an error which is caused by the attempt to set the attributes back onto what remained due to `transclude: element`which, in this case and that of the `ngIf`, is just a marker for where the element has been, in the form of a comment.

To avoid that from happening, [`ngIf`](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js) terminates the process early by having a higher priority, `terminal:true` and by monitoring directly its expression grabbed straight from `$tAttrs`. Interpolation will execute, but this is done at a later stage, by calling the transclusion function the moment the `ngIf` expression turns true, on a clone of the original element, now under its control. The new element will show nice and dandy under the comment element.

[Here is the same sample but fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/MoonStorm/pbd62f2c/). The error condition is avoided.

Comment: The problem mentioned above was [reported and fixed in Angular 1.4.0 Beta 6](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11304).  Element transclusion without rendering an element is properly supported now, hence the ``ng-if`` directive can function either way. Whether the Angular team will allow for its behavior to change is another story.